# Google maps API - geocoder doesn't find 'Carson, CA'

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I have a customer with store locator functionality based on Google maps API. Couple days ago the complained about locator not able to find 'Carson, CA'
Here's a really simple demo from Google itself and it doesn't work either:
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html

Is there a way to contact Google support? I tried to search for any contact information but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like a bug as there is a Carson marked on the map south of Los Angeles. It happens: geocoder data gets updated and sometimes things get missed off. Bugs need to be raised in the issue tracker. Be sure to search first (although I didn't find a previous report for this) and choose the right template when raising a new bug.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

For a store locator app, you may find searching for West Carson provides a decent start point, although this is hardly a usable workaround. Try using the zip code instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link to issues tracker! I opened up a bug ticket, we'll see if they reply.

Comment: I don't know if that was my ticket on google maps issue tracker (because I received a reply that this is data error and I have to file it somewhere else), but anyways it seems to work now. Looks like somebody in google took charge and fixed it. I'm marking your answer as accepted. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is actually a bug; let me gently suggest that I think you are probably using the wrong API for looking up "Carson, CA." I'm not being harsh, just trying to help. But Geocoding has two basic functions:

1. Given an address as input, reply with the best Lat-Lng coordinates for that address.
2. Given coordinates as input, reply with the closest known address (sometimes called Reverse Geocoding).

With "Carson, CA" as input, it doesn't seem like you have given enough information to have defined an address, which probably means that the Geocoder just didn't have enough information. The same goes for the Store Locator; "Carson, CA" isn't a *store*.

I think what you do want to use for a search of this kind is the Google Places API[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), because you are actually looking for a *place*, not coordinates or an address. Using the Google Places Autocomplete, for example, you can set the tool to search for different `types`, for example: `countries`, `cities`, or `geocode` (and there are others). The first, `countries` will let you find places such as: Australia, Bahamas, or Canada. The second, `cities`, will let you find places such as: Albuquerque, Baton Rouge, or *Carson, CA*. The last, `geocode` will restrict you to address searches, which is essentially what you are using when using the Geocoder.

I made the same mistake myself the other day when I sent a request to the Geocoder that contained "Wrigley Field"; the result was some address in Georgia on "Wrigley Field Road," which had me very confused until I thought about it for awhile and then it made sense. Wrigley Field is a *place*, not an address. I have been working with the `Autocomplete` a bunch lately and that has really made the difference between the two modes of lookup clear. As a possible solution for you, if you don't provide a specific `type` to the `Autocomplete`, it will use all of them, which will allow you to find places and/or addresses. It might give you a more functional solution for your site.

Anyway, just trying to offer some helpful feedback and I hope I did help -

Comment: Well, yes... except try Mountain View CA, or West Carson CA. The geocoder has always used the legend on the map tiles for this sort of place. It can't find businesses by name; it's always been able to find towns by name.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well I know _that_! :) I guess I was being too theoretical and I will use whatever works well myself, but my point is that using the Geocoder for searches of that kind is _probably_ not the best way to go. The results feel unpredictable and mixing geocoding in with place searches seems to yield spotty results. "Wrigley Field" sends me to GA, but "Camden Yards" (Orioles home field) takes me right to downtown Baltimore; "West Carson CA" is fine but "Carson CA" is empty. Results like that feel whimsical, whereas the Places API seems more consistent. I like your style Mr. Leach -